# Show a function from the projective line to a cubic curve is a homeomorphism.

Tags: complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

> **Definition.** A *projective curve* $C$ is the zero set $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{C})$ of a homogeneous polynomial in $n+1$ complex variables.

> **Definition.** A polynomial $P \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is said to be *homogeneous* (in the context of this question) if for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ it is true that $P(\lambda x_1, \ldots, \lambda x_n) = \lambda^{\deg(P)} \cdot P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

**Exercise.** Let $C$ be the projective curve, defined as the zero set of the homogeneous polynomial $P(x,y,z) = y^2 z - x^3 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ within $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{C})$. Show that the map $f: \mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{C}) \to C, f[s;t] := [s^2t; s^3; t^3]$ is well-defined and a homeomorphism.

> **Step 1 (PROOF COMPLETE): $f$ is well-defined.** Let $[a,b,c] \in \mathrm{im}(f)$ be the image of the point $[s,t] \in \mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{C})$. W.L.O.G. rescale the coordinates such that $a = 1$. Then, the coordinates of $f[s,t]=[a,b,c]$ satisfy
> \begin{align*}
>         P(a,b,c)
>         = b^2c - a^3
>         = (s^3)^2(t^3) - (s^2t)^3          
>         = s^6t^3 - s^6t^3
>         = 0,
>     \end{align*}
> by which $f[s,t] \in C$, as necessary. Hence, the images of $f$ exist. Let us now show that they are uniquely determined (i.e. that $[a,b]=[c,d] \implies f[a,b]=f[c,d]$):
> Let $[a,b],[c,d] \in \mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{C})$ be points such that $[a,b]=[c,d]$. Then, there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $[c,d] = [\lambda a, \lambda b]$. Hence, it suffices to show uniqueness of the images in the case where the preimages are scalar multiples of one another. In general, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ we have
> \begin{align*}
>         f[\lambda a, \lambda b]
>         = [(\lambda a)^2 (\lambda b), (\lambda a)^3, (\lambda b)^3]
>         = [\lambda^3 a^2 b, \lambda^3 a^3, \lambda^3 b^3]
>         = [a^2 b, a^3, b^3]
>         = f[a,b]
>     \end{align*}
> which finishes this step of the proof.

**What I have been able to do as well.**
I have proved that $f$ is well-defined (see above) and that $f$ is continuous and surjective (both not shown here).

**What I am missing.**
For injectivity, I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: It is a singular (at $[0:0:1]$) irreducible cubic curve, not an elliptic curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the function
$$g\colon C \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$$
$$[x:y:z]\mapsto \begin{cases} [y:x] & \text{if } y \neq 0 \\
[0:1]& \text{if } y=0\end{cases}$$

is a two-sided inverse of $f$. This shows that $f$ is a bijection.

Since the function $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3\setminus\{0\}; (s,t)\mapsto (s^2t,s^3,t^3)$ is continuous, by the universal property of the final topology (a quotient topology is a final topology), the function $h\colon \mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3\setminus\{0\}; [s:t]\mapsto (s^2t,s^3,t^3)$ is continuous. Denote by $\pi\colon \mathbb{C}^3\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^2$ the canonical projection. Then we have $f=\pi\circ h$. Thus, as a composition of continuous functions, the function $f$ is continuous. Now, since $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is compact and $C$ is Hausdorff, the continuous bijection $f$ is a homeomorphism.